# How do I use the Ace dialog to show messages/errors?

Tags: dialog, ace-editor

I use the ace editor with the vim keybindings on my site. Whenever someone goes into normal mode and types a command, it shows up in a dialog at the bottom. I defined a function like so:

```
ace.config.loadModule("ace/keyboard/vim", m => {
  m.CodeMirror.Vim.defineEx("write", "w", () => submitForm())
})
```

The neat thing is, whenever that function errors, it shows the error in another dialog. My question is, is this feature exposed to users? Can I use that dialog to show messages like the editor does when the function errors? Here's a screenshot to show an example:

Typing a command - [image: typing a command]

Error pops up (another dialog in front of the one that I use to type the command) - [image: error pops up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no documented api for this, but judging by 
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.4.9/lib/ace/keyboard/vim.js#L4983, it should be possible to use the following

```
editor.state.cm.openNotification(domNodeOrHtmlString, {bottom: true, duration: 5000})
```

to create the dom node you can use the buildDom function from ace.

```
var domNode = ace.require("ace/lib/dom").buildDom(["span", {style: "color:red"}, "xxxxx"])
```

Comment: Awesome! This works very well. Thank you very much.